# Bootstrap v4 buttongroup (radio button) smaller than button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a dropdown and a multi-toggle (radio buttons) to stay aside of each other. However, I can't get why they keep appearing of different size... I use bootstrap 4.0.

here is the html snippet of my header

```
<div id="header">
    <p style="margin:0px;"><img src="assets/logo2.svg" width="63" height="14" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 0;"></p>
    <h1 id="title">Price Indicies</h1>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown float-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">Boroughs
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Boroughs</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brooklyn hoods</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manhattan hoods</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Queens hoods</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group float-right" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="sales" autocomplete="off">sales</input>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="rentals" autocomplete="off">rentals</input>
        </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the live code:
https://run.plnkr.co/64KRhkyz35xXoeMw/

Comment: Your link: `Oh dear, something didn't go quite right - Internal Server Error`

Comment: You plunker isn't working (server error)

Comment: thanks, seems it works now!

Comment: Also, "dropdown-menu" opening tag is `<div>` and closing tag is `<ul>`. That will cause ya' some problems....

Comment: Radio positions are absolute, which make them vanish somewhere, then just padding them accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want them to the the same heihgt as the drop down button.  Your buttons are smaller because there is no text in them.  If you were to add a space ( ) they would be the size of the normal bootstrap button.  Then you would need to add the `btn-sm` class to make them the same size as the drop down button (or remove that class from the dropdown button).

Comment: I apologize for that copied snipped does not have text, but there is text in the plunker code - within the input, as documented here:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/

Comment: Indeed, I was adding the text to the input flag, while it does not accept anything within - I should have added it to the label instead. Now everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css to have dropdown and radio button of same size

```
   label.btn.btn-primary {
      padding :13px;
  }
```

Comment: it did indeed help to make them ~same size, but not exactly, and still no text is shown

Comment: where and what  text you want

Comment: within the input tag, as stated in the documentation.